# IdHttpServer form caption not updating

Tags: delphi, indy

I know i have posted a similar question before but i am not able to get it working I have this simple code :

```
procedure TfrmMain.srvrConnect(AContext: TIdContext); //idhttpserver on connect event
var
  S,C : String;
begin
 repeat
  s := s + AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadChar;
 until AContext.Connection.Socket.InputBufferIsEmpty = True;
 frmMain.caption := S;
 Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
end;
```

The strings displays ok in the memo but the caption doesn't get updated

Comment: IIRC IdHTTPServer's read/write should take places inside the context, so what you need is to create a subclass of TIdContext that will handle the request/response in a thread created by the server, and from that you can do whatever you need to do, here's a small demo I wrote some time ago http://www.delphigeist.com/2010/12/dynamic-web-pages-with-dwscript-and.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TIdHTTPServer` is a multi-threaded component.  `TIdContext` runs in its own worker thread.  You cannot safely update the Form's `Caption` (or do anything else with the UI) from outside of the main thread.  You need to synchronize with the main thread, such as with the `TIdSync` or `TIdNotify` class.

On a side note, calling `ReadChar()` in a loop is very inefficient, not to mention error-prone if you are using Delphi 2009+ since it cannot return data for surrogate pairs.

Use something more like this instead;

```
type
  TDataNotify = class(TIdNotify)
  protected
    Data: String;
    procedure DoNotify; override;
  public
    constructor Create(const S: String);
    class procedure DataAvailable(const S: String);
  end;

constructor TDataNotify.Create(const S: String);
begin
  inherited Create;
  Data := S;
end;

procedure TDataNotify.DoNotify;
begin
  frmMain.Caption := Data; 
  frmMain.Memo1.Lines.Add(Data); 
end;

class procedure TDataNotify.DataAvailable(const S: String);
begin
  Create(S).Notify;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.srvrConnect(AContext: TIdContext); //idhttpserver on connect event 
var 
  S: String; 
begin 
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(IdTimeoutDefault);
  if not AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  begin
    S := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferAsString; 
    TDataNotify.DataAvailable(S); 
  end;
end;
```

Comment: wierd but i don't recieve anything with AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferAsString; if i use what i wrote it works fine ... any idea why ?

Comment: `InputBufferAsString` takes whatever is currently in the `InputBuffer` and converts it to a `String`.  On D2009+, that involves decoding the bytes to Unicode.  If that decoding fails, such as if the bytes contain incomplete character sequences, that can cause a blank `String` to be returned. Internally, the decoding is based on Embarcadero's `TEncoding` classes, and those classes do not raise exceptions on decode errors. So the real question is - what kind of data are you trying to receive in the first place, and why were you trying to read it 1 character at a time?

Comment: i am receiving data from a gps so the string is not encoded like ascii

Comment: It still has to have some structure to it, the GPS is not going to just pump out random data. Can you show an example of what the data actually looks like?

Comment: instead of ending with 00 byte the string ends with an # caracter

Comment: If a string always ends with a `#` character, then use `ReadLn('#')` and leave the `InputBuffer` alone, eg: `s := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLine('#')`. Even if the line did end with a `00` byte, you could use `ReadLn(#0)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you are writing to the right variable. Are you sure that `frmMain` is the form you want the caption do change?

Also, you could try:

```
procedure TfrmMain.srvrConnect(AContext: TIdContext); //idhttpserver on connect event
var
  S,C : String;
begin
 repeat
  s := s + AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadChar;
 until AContext.Connection.Socket.InputBufferIsEmpty = True;
 oCaption := S;
 TThread.Synchronize(nil, Self.ChangeCaption);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.ChangeCaption;
begin
 Self.Caption := oCaption;
 Memo1.Lines.Add(oCaption);
end;
```

And finally, make sure that the first line on `S` is not a blank line, because the form's caption will not show strings that contains a line feed.

Comment: You cannot safely update the UI from a worker thread (which `TIdContext` runs in), and `Application.ProcessMessages()` does not update the main UI when called from a worker thread.

Comment: `TForm` does not have a `Synchronize()` method, and `ChangeCaption()` is not a mmember of the `TfrmMain` class.  I updated your answer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks! I was in a hurry when I updated the code and I did not use Delphi.